# How to measure noise on an antenna in system

Tags: rf, antenna, radio, emc, interference

I am working on an antenna based RF receiver (AM/FM radio) that appears to be picking up interference from other parts of the circuit.  I want to view the noise spectrum, but the receiver chip doesn't expose the actual RF signal, so it's difficult to obtain the noise information.  You can query the receiver chip via I2C to get a few noise related parameters, but it seems like it would be a lot of work to use that information to get a plot-able spectrum (if it's even possible), so I'd like to avoid doing that if I could.

I am new to working with antennas, so I was wondering if there's an easy way to see what the receiver chip is seeing with some sort of probe and plot it out on a oscilloscope or spectrum analyzer.  My first though was to use a low capacitance differential probe between the antenna and ground and plot the FFT on the scope.  See below

[image]

My concerns are that **a)** the probe would load down the antenna and change the antenna response so that I'm not seeing the real noise profile that the system will see, and **b)** the signal would be so small that I might not be able to see the offending frequencies.

Do anyone have any recommendations or insights?

Comment: How do you know _where_ it is picking up noise if you can't measure it? The most likely place is at the antenna, in which case you should be able to measure it with a spec straight at the antenna input. Start there - if the antenna input looks ok then you can deduct that the noise is picked up on-board. If the input looks bad, then the source is radiated emissions.

Comment: I don't know where the noise is coming from, which is why I want to measure it at the input of the RF receiver.  That's a good idea to try to determine whether or not there is noise is coming in from the antenna though.  Even if I see noise on the antenna though, that still doesn't prove that there isn't additional noise at the RF input that's not coming from the antenna.  I'm looking for a way to measure full noise that the RF chip sees.

Comment: What receiver chip are you using?

Comment: Si4731 from Silicon Labs

Comment: Bring an electric mixer, or blender, near your radio. See what happens. Then find someone with a spectrum analyzer, and bring the mixer/blender **near** that, with a 6" wire on input to the analyzer.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, I don't understand what you are trying to say.  Are you saying that you can pickup EMI with a spectrum analyzer and a piece of wire as an antenna?

Comment: How do I look at electrical signals? Erm, oscilloscope? (a fast oscilloscope, and fast diff probe)